# Zoom Function in a Webview with Electron

Tags: javascript, html, webview, electron

I'm trying to create a zoom in and a zoom out button for my webview in my Electron app.

Currently, I did it like this but `getZoomFactor` always returns `undefined`. Is there another way of creating these two zoom buttons?

```
function zoomIn() {
    const webview = document.querySelector('webview');
    let actualZoom = webview.getZoomFactor();
    if (actualZoom == null) {
        actualZoom = 1;
    }
    webview.setZoomFactor(actualZoom + 1);
}

function zoomOut() {
    const webview = document.querySelector('webview');
    let actualZoom = webview.getZoomFactor();
    if (actualZoom == null) {
        actualZoom = 1;
    }
    webview.setZoomFactor(actualZoom - 1);
}
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebView's getZoomLevel takes a callback instead of returning a value.

> .getZoomLevel(callback)
>   callback Function
>
> zoomLevel Number
>   Sends a request to get current zoom level, the callback will be called with callback(zoomLevel).